# Thymeleaf doesn't apply the css in my html file

Tags: html, css, pdf, thymeleaf

I am trying to generate a PDF using ThymeLeaf. I'd like to apply style to my PDF using CSS. I've already done it by linking a CSS file in the html file, but this time I'd like to put the CSS in the html file in a `<style></style>`.

Here is the HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print"/>
      <title>PDF Report</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">* {
      font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: justify;
  }

  h4{
      color : darkblue;
  }

  h2{
      color : #262626;
  }

  img {
      width: 400px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;

  }

  div.header {
      display: block; text-align: center;
      position: running(header);
      background-color: gold;
  }
  div.footer {
      background-color: #262626;
      color: white;
      display: block; text-align: center;
      position: running(footer);
  }
  div.content {page-break-after: always;}
  @page {
      @top-center { content: element(header) }
  }
  @page {
      @bottom-center { content: element(footer) }
  }</style><body>

  <div class='header'>my first report header</div>
  <div class='footer'>my first report footer</div>

  <h1>[[${reportTitle}]]</h1><h2>[[${docTitle1}]]</h2>
  <h4>[[${docUrl1}]]</h4>
  <div>[[${docContent1}]]</div>
  <br/>
  <img src="document1.jpg"/><h2>[[${docTitle2}]]</h2>
  <h4>[[${docUrl2}]]</h4>
  <div>[[${docContent2}]]</div>
  <br/>
  <img src="document2.jpg"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

Actually, it just read the CSS as plain text and it doesn't apply the style. Is there anything I am doing wrong or is this just not possible to apply CSS without an external file?

Comment: Try putting the `<style>` tag inside the `<head>`. Currently, it's in between the `<head>` and `<body>` sections of your HTML page.

Comment: Indeed that was the solution ! I should really get some knowledge on html and css...